# Convert Military time to string representation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an column declared as `int` (called HourMil) which stores the time in [military format](http://www.spacearchive.info/military.htm). I need to convert this values to an formatted string (HH:MM)

example

```
HourMil  = 710 -> must be 07:10
HourMil  = 1305 -> must be 13:05
```

Actually I am using this code (and works ok) for convert the column HourMil to the string representation.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT('0',4-LEN(CAST(HourMil AS VARCHAR)))+CAST(HourMil AS VARCHAR),1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(LEFT('0',4-LEN(CAST(HourMil AS VARCHAR)))+CAST(HourMil AS VARCHAR),3,2) FROM MYTABLE
```

but I think this code can be improved.

Comment: Actually, that "military" format (24-hour format) is what the **VAST** majority of the world uses - everyone except the US, pretty much.... why not just call it "International" or "Standard" time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a date, then formatting it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEADD
   (hh, HourMil / 100, DATEADD(mi, HourMil % 100, '1900-01-01')), 8), 0, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Equations:

```
H = HourMil / 100;
M = HourMil - ( HourMil / 100 ) * 100;
```

Examples of working:

```
H = 710 / 100 = 7
M = 710 - (710 / 100) * 100 = 10

H = 1305 / 100 = 13
M = 1305 - (1305 / 100) * 100 = 5
```

Note: All **/*** operators **MUST** working under decimal numbers only. (integers)

Then you SQL will be:

```
CONCAT(CAST(H AS VARCHAR(8)), ':', CAST(M AS VARCHAR(8)));
```

With equations final seems to be:

```
CONCAT(CAST((HourMil / 100) AS VARCHAR(8)), ':', CAST((HourMil - ( HourMil / 100 ) * 100) AS VARCHAR(8)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method and also a shortest one

```
select stuff(right('0'+ltrim(hourmail),4),3,0,':') from
(
select 710 as hourmail union all
select 1305
) as t
```